# Beginner question: Problems using a function on each combination of two lists of a custom type

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I'm currently studying for an exam in an entry level university course in which we use Haskell mainly to simulate combinational circuits. I have basic problems with Haskell itself, knowing next to nothing of functional programming and coming from a basic level of understanding of Java which further complicates things.

I am trying to build a function which uses and prints all combinations of two lists of my custom type in a comparator. I am working with the following (working as intended) snippets:

```
type Nibble = (Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool) 
comparator :: Nibble -> Nibble -> Bool 
comparator (a3,a2,a1,a0) (b3,b2,b1,b0) = nor [a3<+>b3, a2<+>b2, a1<+>b1, a0<+>b0]
```

Using list comprehension I got a list containing all 4-tuples of my custom type. I am trying to use each element of my two lists to get the output of comparator for every possible combination of my custom type.

I tried building a function that takes the head of each of two lists and uses them with the comparator function to then recursively start with the rest of the list. I struggle with basically every part of that function and I think I am going down the wrong path.

I am looking for resources that can point me in the right direction/ towards the right concepts I need to look at and maybe a suggestion on how I should approach similar problems since I struggle with the concept of functional programming and combining multiple functions. I have no idea where and how to start. I'm working with learnyouahaskell however they seem to jump from very easy to quite complex examples very quickly while skipping most topics I need.

I'd much appreciate if anyone could point me in a direction. Thanks a lot in advance!
Please excuse any shortcomings in the description of my problem. Its my first time writing anything on stackoverflow. I will clarify everything I missed in edits.

Edit:Thanks for the feedback, I'm trying to clarify but I'm struggling with both, the language, the vocabulary, my distinct lack of programming skills and the understanding of the terminology required.

The comparator function intends to simulate a comparator circuit by testing whether two 4-bit numbers, here represented by Nibbles, are the same. I intend to try this function on every possible combination of two 4-bit numbers. My idea was to take a list
`nibTab = [(a,b,c,d) | a <- [False, True], b <- [False, True],c <- [False, True],d <- [False, True]]`, using it as input list 1 and input list 2. Both lists are supposed to look like this, which I think I already achieved:
`[(True, True, True, True), (True,True,True,False),...,(False,False,False,False)]`

I'm trying to print a string for each comparison and with the two answers actually got it to work.

```
compRow :: [String]  
compRow =  
  [show x ++ " , " ++ show y ++ " : " ++ show (comparator x y)  
  | x <- nibTab, y <- nibTab]  
  where  
    nibTab = [(a,b,c,d) | a <- [False, True], b <- [False, True],c <- [False, True],d <- [False, True]]  

compList :: [String] -> String  
compList [] = ""  
compList (x:xs) = show x ++ "\n" ++ compList xs
```

I had a smaller example to work with. Here we checked whether our definition of an XOR-Operator worked as intended. I got lost trying to identify how the type signatures for my task at hand had to look like and with writing appropriate functions that tried to imitate the example below:

```
(<+>) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
(<+>) a b = (a || b) && (not (a && b))

table_row :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> (Bool, Bool) -> String
table_row f (x, y) = show (x,y)++ ":" ++ show (f x y)

table :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> [(Bool, Bool)] -> String
table f [] = ""
table f (x:xs) =  table_row f x ++ "\n" ++ table f xs

checkTable = do
  let bool_duo [(a,b) | a <- [False,True], b <- [False,True]]
  putStrLn (table (<+>) bool_duo)
```

Comment: It isn't clear what input you have and what output you want to get. Where are the two lists?

Comment: I added that to my post. To sum it up: Im trying to get the output of my comparator function for every possible combination of two instances of my custom type. A perfect output would be for example: (True, True, False, False)(True,True,False, True) : False

Comment: It's still not clear to me; I don't see what your description of the problem has to do with the “perfect output” example, which seems to do something quite different. — I suggest you add some Java/Python/pseudocode implementation of what you're trying to do, and make sure it contains all the information needed to solve the problem in unambiguous form.

Comment: I don't understand what are the two lists you are trying to combine and what output you are trying to get from it. Your question does not contain two lists. It contains one, and it's not an input. I expect a question of this format: my first input list is `[....]`, my second input list is `[...]` and my expected output is `...`. Any code you have tried in process is an added bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already seen list comprehensions. You can use that to call a function with all the elements in a list you already have. E.g.

```
results :: [String]
results = 
   [ "The square of " ++ show x ++ " is " ++ show (square x)
   | x <- allInputs ]
   where
   square y  = y*y
   allInputs = [0..10]  -- an example
```

Above, `square` only has one argument. If you have more, add a generator to the list comprehension.

```
results :: [String]
results = 
   [ "The comparison of " ++ show x ++ " and " ++ show y
     ++ " is " ++ show (comparator x y)
   | x <- allInputs, y <- allInputs ]
   where
   allInputs = ....  -- your list with all the inputs to try
```

If you don't want a list of strings, adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what you want to do, but my best guess is something like this:

```
bools = [True, False]
all_nibbles = [(a,b,c,d) | a <- bools, b <- bools, c <- bools, d <- bools]
all_results = [comparator x y | x <- all_nibbles, y <- all_nibbles]
```

This code uses list comprehensions to first build a list of all possible nibbles, then compute the results of your function when applied to all possible combinations of nibbles.

For future reference:

- in Haskell, `(a,b,c,d)` is a tuple:

  - tuples are fixed-length, and
  - each element of a tuple can have a different type.
- in Haskell, `[a,b,c,d]` is a list:

  - lists are variable-length, and
  - each element of a list must have the same type